# Adding AWG Noise with standard deviation of 1.75, to the signal generated in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm quite new to Matlab and I'm kind of stuck.

This is what the question is asking for.

Add AWG Noise with standard deviation of 1.75, to the signal you just generated.

This is the signal code:

```
fs = 20000; %Sample Rate (Hz)
f = 1200; %frequency of signal
A = 2.5; % amplitude of signal
phi = pi / 4;
t = [0:(1/fs):0.05] ;
y = A * sin ( 2 * pi * f * t + phi ) + 3;
% sine wave 1 [Hz], phase shift 0°, amplitude of 1 vpp
plot ( t, y ); %Plot the waveform you just created
%Label the axis and title the plot
xlabel ( 'time [sec]' );
ylabel ( 'amplitude [volt]' );
xlim([0 0.05])
ylim([0 6])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate Gaussian noise samples with a standard deviation of 1.75 as '1.75 * randn(1, numel(y))'. The command 'randn' generates Gaussian pseudorandom numbers with mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1. Here is your code with added Gaussian noise:

```
        fs = 20000; %Sample Rate (Hz)

        f = 1200; %frequency of signal

        A = 2.5; % amplitude of signal

        phi = pi / 4;

        t = [0:(1/fs):0.05] ;

        y = A * sin ( 2 * pi * f * t + phi ) + 3; % sine wave 1 [Hz], phase shift 0°, amplitude of 1 vpp

        n = 1.75 * randn(1, numel(y)); % AWGN with a standard deviation of 1.75

        fprintf('The standard deviation of the added noise is %f \n ', std(n));

        figure;

        plot ( t, y ); %Plot the waveform you just created

        %Label the axis and title the plot

        xlabel ( 'time [sec]' );

        ylabel ( 'amplitude [volt]' );

        xlim([0 0.05])

        ylim([0 6])

        figure; 

        plot(t, y + n); 

        xlabel ( 'time [sec]' );

        ylabel ( 'amplitude [volt]' );
```

The standard deviation of the noise changes significantly with every run. If you increase the number of samples in 't', the standard deviation of the generated noise will be very stable.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it.